# Prohibit adding more public methods than in interface

Tags: typescript

```
interface IHuman {
    talk(): void;
    walk(): void;
}

class Human implements IHuman {
    talk() {
    }

    walk() {
    }

    // This should not be possible:
    fly() {
    }
}
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler that only public methods defined in the interface are allowed to be added?

Or in other words, disabling duck typing in certain situations?

Comment: AFAIK, no. What's the rationale? Also, this has nothing to do with duck typing. Strongly typed languages (Java, etc.) also authorize having more methods in classes implementing interfaces. They would be useless otherwise.

Comment: The rationale is to make sure that everybody uses interfaces instead of implementations across the codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [exact types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), which TypeScript doesn't currently have (as of TS 2.4) .  It doesn't look like there are immediate plans to implement it either, as it would probably interact weirdly with how the type checker deals with generics.  If you think your use case is compelling enough, you might want to comment on [the issue in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).

---

Maybe you can get what you want in a different way?  For example,

```
type Constructor<T> = {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
  readonly prototype: T;
}

// your interface is now a class
class IHuman {
  talk():void {throw new Error("nope")}
  walk():void {throw new Error("sorry")}
  private constructor() {
     // nobody can subclass or instantiate IHuman from outside
  }
  static implement(talkImpl: () => void, walkImpl: () => void): Constructor<IHuman> {
    return class extends IHuman {
      talk() {
        talkImpl();
      } 
      walk() {
        walkImpl();
      }
      constructor() {
        super();
      }
    }
  }
}        

var Human = IHuman.implement(
  () => { console.log('Hello!') }, 
  () => { console.log("I'm walkin', here!") }
);
var human = new Human();
human.talk();
human.walk();
```

This forces anyone who wants to get a subclass of `IHuman` to call `IHuman.implement()` which will only allow the caller to implement the `talk()` and `walk()` methods.  This is probably unpleasant for everyone involved, but it may be the closest you can get for now.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to [exact types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)!